# Cocoapod modules not available in Pod Example project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I created a new Pod project and included an example project when running through the `pod lib create ProjectName` setup steps.

I've added some classes to the pod and although I am able to use them in a separate project that includes my pod either locally or remotely, I can't use them in the Example project within the pod project.

I've published the pod here: https://github.com/sbiermanlytle/ViprUi

Here's an example of when I try to use my pod in the Example Project ViewController: https://github.com/sbiermanlytle/ViprUi/blob/master/Example/ViprUi/ViewController.swift

[image]

That module is defined as:

```
public struct ViUi { ... }
```

What do I need to do in order to use the Pod's modules in the Pod's example project?